# ipa was not installed on the iphone because it does not work with this version of ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

i send an ipa distribution enterprise, when the client try to installed it on a iphone with last version 12.1.2 he got this error :

[image]

translation :  ipa was not installed on the iphone because it does not work with this version of ios

i add udid iphone on console apple developper, also i tested ipa on my device with version ios 9 and it's work

how can i resolve this error please ?

Comment: If it is enterprise signed then the UDID is not required. What version of Xcode did you build with? Does your build include 64 bit code. iOS 11 and later do not support 32 bit only builds.

Comment: i tried to export ipa developpement and i add udid, and it was the same error

Comment: @Paulw11 i use xcode 9, how can i check if it support 64 bit too ? i have enable bitcode = no

Comment: Upgrade to Xcode 10 and ensure your project is using the iOS 12 base SDK. You need to ensure your project has 64 bit support. Either upgrade your device to iOS 12 or get access to another device that has iOS 12 so that you can test properly.

Comment: Thank you for your responses i will do that.

Comment: Make sure the valid architectures in the build settings are "arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s"

Comment: as Paulw11 mentioned updating the xcode to 10 will fix the issue if the client is trying to install in iOS 12 or above devices. Also make sure that while archiving, you select "Generic iOS Device" instead of any preselected device or simulator which might cause this issue.

Comment: I just export  with xCode 12 and checked on a iPhone with ios 12 and it's work thank you @Paulw11 for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Paulw11 Said i had to upload my xcode from 9 to 10, and export again this resolve my problem